# How to change the Foreground of a ProgressBar in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

Can anyone tell me how I can change the Forground of a ProgressBar to Yellow when I press a button and also when the bar gets under 50%?
I tried some things out, but none of them worked.

I'm using C# and WPF.

Comment: Which progress bar? .NET has several. Add the namespace and UI framework you're using.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ it's WPF

Comment: @KenKaneki Then it should be simple. What did you try?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ i'm new to it , so i just began with:   ` prg_life.foreground = ..... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the Foreground color of a ProgressBar in WPF, create a new `Brush` and assign it to the Foreground like this:

```
prg_life.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
```

And to change it once the value goes below 50:

```
private void prg_life_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if (e.NewValue < (0.5 * prg_life.Maximum)) 
    {
        prg_life.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
    }
}
```

Add the above event-handler method to the ValueChanged event of the ProgressBar and you will be good to go.

<sub>**Note**: I used Orange because Yellow looks horrible. But you can use any color you like! You can also use gradients and images as the Foreground. For info, look below.</sub>

**More Info**:

- [Colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Brushes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970904(v=vs.100).aspx)